# How to use classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

Hi i am continue getting undefined error in alert when i am trying to access my class veriable from out side of class, i have made a main class and then use prototype to add some object into my class which i want to access from anywhere by creating new class please help me

```
    function initShell(){
    XMLLoader.prototype.loadXML('xml/scq.xml', initShell.prototype.loadData);
    alert(this.currentQue);
}

initShell.prototype.loadData = function(xmlRef){
    this.currentQue = 0;
    this.pageList = xmlRef.getElementsByTagName("mission");
}

var p1 = new initShell;

alert(p1.currentQue);
```

Comment: Please give the full error you get and any relevant code to help people willing to help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Edit :**

Working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sq7a09us/1/)

```
// Define a class like this
function initShell(currentQue, pageList){

   // Add object properties like this
   this.currentQue= currentQue;
   this.pageList= pageList;
}

// Add methods like this.  All initShell objects will be able to invoke this
initShell.prototype.speak = function(){
    alert("Value of currentQue is : " + this.currentQue);
};

// Instantiate new objects with 'new'
var initShellObj = new initShell("A", "B");

// Invoke methods like this
initShellObj.speak();
```